# Cant establish new connection in oracle sql developer on linux machine?

Tags: linux, oracle

I was following [this guys](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/installing-sqldeveloper-4-on-mint-and-ubuntu-minus-the-alien/#comment-76091) advice on how to install oracle sql developer on my linux mint. Im still new to linux, but I followed his installation process line by line. Now my problem is whenever I try to create a new connection, during the test I get "test failed IO error: The network adapter could not establish a connection". As I understood I couldnt even open the developer unless I properly pointed to the jdk, so I am guessing that is not the problem or am I mistaking?

Comment: Are you sure you're entering the right information for the connection to your database? Is the database up and running? Can you connect to it with sqlplus?

Comment: define right information? untill now I tried entering my linux root details for user and pass, for conn name I just  put test, and the rest I left to default. I dod try to change the sid from xe to orcl and still no results.

How do I connect it to sql plus? Developer is the only thing I have installed

Comment: SQL Developer is an "IDE". That's it. It doesn't come with a database. You need to actually install & configure a database (or use an existing database) if you want to be able to connect to something.

Comment: @Mat huge newbie here, what should my next step be in order to connect to a DB, which one should I install?

Comment: If you need an Oracle database, install that. If you need something else, install something else. If you have no idea what sort of database you need, I suggest you stay clear of Oracle for now, and look for tutorials on Postgres or MySQL (and their respective tools).